# Remove Duplicate Windows 10 Boot Drive

Tags: windows, boot

I have a Windows 10 machine with three hard drives

C: 256GB SSD that boots Windows (or so I assumed)
S: 1TB SSD for additional storage
D: 1TB HDD for additional storage

I'm upgrading parts of my machine and decided to get rid of the old "D" HDD. I was unable to boot my computer with just the first two drives (BIOS was unable to locate a bootable device) until I finally figured out that I needed to reconnect the HDD to boot my machine.

I don't remember when, but I must have installed Windows 7/10 on the HDD at some point years ago. How can I get rid of the HDD?

Disk Management indicates that the "C" drive is Healthy (Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition) and has a Recovery Partition. Drive D is just Healthy (System, Active, Primary Partition).

System Configuration shows I have one bootable version of Windows 10, and that it is coming from C:\WINDOWS.

I can't understand why Windows 10 needs the old "D" drive to work.

Comment: What do you see when you run `BCDEdit.exe` and/or `MSConfig.exe` on the boot tab?

Comment: MSconfig.exe opened System Configuration, while BCDEdit.exe indicated Windows Boot Loader on C:/, but Windows Boot Manager on D:/. Sounds like I can use BCDEdit.exe to point the Boot Manager to C:/?

Comment: Yes, try this `Bcdedit /set {bootmgr} device partition=C:` more BCDedit doc at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766223(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I will do that when I get home and update this question with how it went.

Comment: No luck. I ran that and the Boot Manager changed to partition=C:. I removed the HDD and BIOS wasn't able to locate a bootable drive. Plugged the HDD back in, Windows booted up normally.

Comment: (I figure there's a way to reset the boot loader on Windows 10, and I'm reading some other docs now)